# What template does Django use to add and change in admin?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have this file:

```
templates/admin/{app_name}/{model_name}/add/change_form.html
```

This extends

```
admin/change_form.html
```

I added a button to this template and it is working fine **WHEN** **adding** a new instance of the model.

I want to add another button the template that appears **WHEN changing** already existing instance of a model. So I created this file:

```
templates/admin/{app_name}/{model_name}/change/change_form.html
```

thinking that add and change use the same template. But changes I made to this template do not seem to take place.

What template does Django use when changing the fields of already existing instance of a model?

Comment: put `change_form.html` in `templates/admin/{app_name}/{model_name}/`

Comment: @HasanRamezani thanx :) It turned out that if you put it in {app_name}/{model_name} it affects on change, but if you put it in add folder it affects on add

Comment: are your sure that id you put `change_form.html` in `{app_name}/{model_name}/add` it change add object template?

Comment: i use `django 1.7`, and it not work for me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `change_form_template` in your model admin.

By default it's (in this order):

1. admin/APP/MODEL/change_form.html
2. admin/APP/change_form.html
3. admin/change_form.html

The model properties could be passed in GET to the template url.